# How to lower cpu usage resulted from GC activity

Tags: performance, garbage-collection

in Java system when GC activity increases, would scaling up cpu help performance?
I guess adding more cpu would make system more reliable, but doubt about increasing actual performance.
Adding more memory seems to be direct help, but not be an instant solution because increasing heap size require tests and optimization.
Please share how you experts think avout this.

Trying to lower cpu usage resulted from garbage collection activity by adding more cpu

Comment: AFAIK, no, or at least not much. having few available core help, but when many are available, adding more core should not help. I am not sure the GC runs in parallel but it is a rather memory bound operation and memory accesses tends not to scale with the number of core anyway. If it is parallel, then having more core tends to increase the work-sharing/synchronization parallel overhead. I would argue that the best is to reduce the number of allocation in the first place rather than trying to optimize the GC collection time.

Comment: Thank u, in the first place. 
Then what about scaling out approach? 
Adding more server to the cluster would increase overall memory size. Since we cannot reduce the number of allocation, wouldn’t this be some solution?

Comment: Also, when the same thing took place in other system with cms gc the other time, adding more cpu definitely helped. How cms gc is different from parallel gc from cpu perspective?

Comment: Unless you have a unusual configuration, the GC of Java operate on the local VM so it does not perform any distributed collection. Thus, having more machine change nothing to the behaviour of the GC on a specific machine. The memory is not shared between computing nodes on mainstream systems (there are some system with an hardware shared memory or some distributed shared memory software abstractions but they are not mainstream). It is hard to help you without much more details about your environment/hardware and what you really try to do more precisely.